# How to Apply Dynamic Themes In Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am creating Silverlight Application. In My Application I want to add Functionality for dynamically change Themes. Like I have two Themes(Blue.xaml, Gray.xaml).
And In My Home Page there are two button which is Blue and Gray. I want to Change Theme based on Button Click.
Can any one help me?

Thnx in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) has Theming support (use the latest Silverlight 5 Toolkit - December 2011)

use Theme control and set ThemeUri in controls

```
 <toolkit:Theme x:Name="ThemeContainer"
          ThemeUri="/System.Windows.Controls.Theming.BubbleCreme;component/Theme.xaml">
    <Button>
         ....
    </Button>
 </toolkit:Theme>
```

Ref :http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2010/05/31/dynamically-apply-and-change-theme-with-the-silverlight-toolkit.aspx

Comment: Thanks Dipak, But I already visit this link and it will not help me.
Because I have two Project for Themes and i used it in my main Silverlight Application. Then how to i change Dynamically theme.
Please send me Sample if Possible.
Thanks in Advance.